# Comparing verto and vertor

Tags: vocabulary, verbs, word-comparison, deponent-verbs

Here I have two words:

> *verto, vertere, verti, versum (versus)*
>   *vertor, verti, versus sum, —* (I assume it's deponent)

They both mean "turn" according to the Cambridge Latin Course Book V, but a quick search on wikitionary of *vertor* says:

> first-person singular present passive indicative of *vertō*

Does anyone know whether *vertor* actually exists, and if so, why it does and it's difference to *verto*?

Comment: Grumio est in culina!

Comment: They're the same word (and it really exists),  but it is not really passive,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no separate *vertor*; they're the same word. However, it's not truly passive. *Verto* in the passive can have a middle sense, i.e. where you are the actor doing the action to yourself. The OLD spells it out clearly:

> 3. (pass. in middle sense, cf. *uersor*) To go to and fro, move about (in a place). **b** (of affairs, etc.) to be involved (in difficulties). **b** to be active, occupy oneself (in a sphere). **d** (usu. leg. of factors) to be involved (in a case).